# how to set jquery datetimepicker mindate is tomorrow

Tags: jquery, html, datetimepicker

My jquery code:

```
$('#DatePicker').datetimepicker({
        timepicker : false,
        format : 'd.m.Y',
        minDate : 0
    });
```

In this jquery i am using datetimepicker plugin.i want set min date is tomorrow date.in this code i set min date is today.how to set min date is tomorrow date.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answer for this qustion:

```
$('#DatePicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker : false,
    format : 'd.m.Y',
    minDate : '-1969/12/31'
});
```

it's working fine.

Comment: I get the following message: `Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.`

Comment: Why the heck its 1969

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
 $("input.DateFrom").datepicker({
    minDate: 1 
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2CZtV/349/)**

**Update:**

```
 var tomorrow = new Date(today.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
 $('#DatePicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker : false,
    format : 'd.m.Y',
    startDate: tomorrow
});
```

Comment: your solution is correct,but i am using datetimepicker plugin.i set mindate :1 datetimepicker not worked.

Comment: here the link about datetimepicker plugin:http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: @nmkkannan: try the second demo

Comment: @nmkkannan That link would have been supremely useful in the original question.  There are about a hundred date-time pickers that can be invoked by jQuery.

Comment: @nmkkannan: have you tried changing minDate to startDate

Comment: yes but i want disable previous date.if use startDate previous date not disabled.

Comment: According to doc they should. can you create fiddle.

Comment: i got the answer set minDate : '-1969/12/31'

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
minDate : "+1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#DatePicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker : false,
    format : 'd.m.Y',
    minDate:'+1970/01/02'
});
```

I guess it will do what you want.