# How to manipulate commencement date and resumption date using JQuery Date in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 application, I am using jQuery-1.12.4 for my datepicker

I have Leave Commencement Date and Leave Resumption Date

```
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Commencement Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="commencement_date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="commencement_date" value="{{old('commencement_date')}}" >
            </div>
          </div>                                         

          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Resumption Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="resumption_date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="resumption_date" value="{{old('resumption_date')}}" >
            </div>
          </div>                                         

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function () {
            $('#commencement_date').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
              
            });
            $('#resumption_date').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',                
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I make:

1. Minimum Date in Commencement Date to be current day and Max. Date to be Last Day of the year
2. Minimum Date in Resumption Date to be current day + 1 (add a day to current day) and Max. Date to be Last Day of the year

Thanks

Comment: You'll get a better response if you show that you've made some effort, eg show us what you've tried, why you tried that, describe what happens, etc. We're here bcs we want to help, but SO isn't a code-writing service.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There are *many* questions with answers here for both of the questions you ask, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130249/datepicker-limit-current-year, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128077/how-to-set-maxdate-is-last-day-of-december-on-current-year, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086584/datepicker-mindate-today-and-maxdate-31-dec-next-year, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785509/how-to-set-jquery-datetimepicker-mindate-is-tomorrow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371800/datepicker-set-two-dates-with-startdate-tomorrow  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JS `Date` method, and add a day.  Then attach within datePicker using [minDate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) and [MaxDate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)

```
var commencementDate = new Date();
var resumptionDate = new Date();

// add a day to the Resumption Date
resumptionDate.setDate(resumptionDate.getDate() + 1);

$('#commencement_date').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      minDate: commencementDate,
      maxDate: new Date(year, 11, 31)
          
});
$('#resumption_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', 
    minDate: resumptionDate ,
    maxDate: new Date(year, 11, 31)               
});
```